If coNP ⊆ NP, does that mean coNP = NP?
I had an exam, and one of the questions was
Does ZPP = BPP if coNP ⊆ ZPP.
I came down to coNP ⊆ NP and went on with "then coNP = NP", am i right?

Yes. Assume co-NP ⊆ NP. Take any NP problem. Its complement is co-NP, therefore NP by co-NP ⊆ NP, so the problem itself is co-NP, QED.
